# How does Django Timezone Work?

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

So, in my settings I have the following:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Copenhagen'
```

However, when I issue:

```
timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 26, 8, 47, 15, 862729, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

And the time is two hours late.

I was reading the documentation and I could see that this method calls datetime.datetime() and the information there is correct. I could see the output is based on variable TIME_ZONE, which is set to my current location. Shouldn't timezone.now() get the correct TIME_ZONE time then?

Another question: Does datetime.datetime() gets the information from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it gets information from the machine which runs the code.
2. No, it doesn't give you local time. No, it doesn't use timezone from your settings ([doc ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now), [code ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/utils/timezone/#now)). It uses UTC time (`Europe/Copenhagen` is UTC+2).
3. If you want to get local datetime object you should make it naive:

   ```
   timezone.make_naive(timezone.now(), timezone.get_current_timezone())
   ```

Comment: I have added timezone.now to my models.py in order to stamp modification time in some classes. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: why would you suggest to use a naive datetime object? If `USE_TZ=True` then `timezone.now().astimezone(timezone.get_current_timezone())` returns an aware datetime object in the current timezone. Though you don't need to call `.astimezone()` manually; there is `timezone.localtime()` that does it for you and the corresponding template filter (`localtime`) that you also don't need to call if `USE_TZ=True`

Answer (score 1):

The important thing about timezone-aware datetimes is not which timezone they happen to be stored in, but the fact that they represent a single point in time. When that is true it's trivial (well, *possible*, anyway) to display the datetime in whatever timezone you want.

So the way Django works is that all aware datetimes are stored in UTC. (Even so, they may or not be returned from the database in UTC, depending on the database setup.) Then it offers you tools (e.g. the `TIME_ZONE` setting and [`activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone)) to set the timezone that should be used when rendering templates for user display.

So everything you described is by design.

Comment: If I set my timezone on settings.py and latter I call timezone.now(), shouldn't it return the correct time? As I mentioned, it returns a time object two yours earlier.

Comment: @E.Camilo: 8am in UTC and 10am in Europe/Copenhagen (with DST) *are the exact same moment in time*. So it is the correct time. The `TIME_ZONE` setting tells Django the default timezone for user display, it doesn't affect what timezone is used in Python objects. If you really want to convert it, you can (see #2 [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#usage)), but that's an uncommon use case.

Comment: I thought when I set the timezone to "Europe/Copenhagen", the timezone reference would be automatically set to UTC+2. That is what is making me confused.